# Access Raw Outgoing NetStream Data in Flex/AIR

Tags: apache-flex, streaming, air, netstream

I have a Flex/AIR desktop application that connects a local camera and microphone to a NetStream for delivery to a Flash media server.

However, I would also like to archive a copy of the outgoing stream locally on the filesystem.  Is there any access to the actual bytestream of a NetStream object (even in the dreaded mx.internal namespace) that I could turn around and feed to a FileStream for the local archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't exactly possible since Flash is asynchronous.  Flash (or Air) doesn't have a lot of good support for streams as it is currently.  There has been some [attempts at recording video](http://www.zeropointnine.com/blog/assets_code/SimpleFlvWriter.as.txt), but sound is another thing.

I think the only viable solution would be to package your Air application with a 'server' application that you can send the stream to, which then saves the file to the hard drive.